# People born on Amavasya

Tags: scripture, astrology, amavasya

There are many beliefs regarding the people who born on Amavasya.

Do scriptures comment about people who born on Amavasya? If yes, what are those comments?

Answer (score 3):

The astrological treatise [Hora Ratnam](https://www.astrojyoti.com/effects-and-results-of-birth-in-tithis-and-weekdays.htm) mentions some features that natives born on Amavasya Tithis have:

> 475. Chaturdasi: One born on Chaturdasi (fourteenth day) will perform every undertaking flawlessly. He will be intelligent, bereft of
>      sickness and will ever patronize his relatives.
> 476. Purnima: One born on Purnima (Full Moon) will possess abundance (of things), will have steadiness (of fortunes), ever satisfied,
>      highly fortunate and highly virtuous.
> 477. **Amavasya: One born on Amavasya (New Moon) will have injured organs (or will possess uncontrolled senses), be happy, highly
>      fortunate, weak-bodied and be full of mental distresses.**
>
> The effects of Thithi, Nakshatra, Yoga and Karana, as arrived at based
> on the instructions of canonical treatises, should be noted down in
> the horoscope of birth.

So, there are some positive features some negative as is the case with just about everything else in life.